# Google analytics on Android app setup

Tags: android, google-analytics

So I wanted to add `Google Analytics` to my `Android` app.
So I followed the guide they give:

```
Getting Started

1. Updating AndroidManifest.xml
2. Adding EasyTracker methods
3. Creating your analytics.xml file
```

That's done but then I see [**advanced configuration**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced#set-send)
So I don't really understand what is going on;

Is this advanced config something extra you can put or I need it for the basic analytic?

And in case I need to add this advanced config, do I need to do those steps in every single `Activity`? or just in one? The manual does not give too many hints about it.

Have to say that my app is 4 activities that jump one to each other.( 1 `splashScreenActivity`, 2 `configurationActivities` and 1 main`WebViewActivity`)
I don't have a class that extends `Application`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Getting Started tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) adding EasyTracker methods to your activities allows you following 1) App installations, 2) Active users and demographics, 3) Screens and user engagement, 4) Crashes and exceptions. If this information is enough for your analysis then you do not need to add the advanced config.